# How can I apply filters in my class that extends Walker_Nav_Menu?

Tags: filters, walker

I have the following piece of abridged code:

```
<?php 
class New_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {


function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
    $output .= '<li><a'. $attributes .'>';
    $output .= apply_filters( 'the_title', 'modifyTitle', $item->ID );
    $output .= '</a></li>';
}
function modifyTitle($title){
    return $title . asd;
}
}
?>
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`apply_filters()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters) applies a set of registered (with [`add_filter()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter)) callbacks.

When you apply a filter make sure its name is not one of the [reserved ones](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference), `the_title` looks dangerously "collissible" with other filters.

Your filter application is almost correct, but the 'modifyTitle' bit is not required...

```
// apply the filter
apply_filters( 'wpse31787_the_title', $item->ID );
```

...instead you have to register a filter for `wpse31787_the_title` during your initialization

```
function __construct() {
    add_filter( 'wpse31787_the_title', array($this, 'modifyTitle') );
}
```

And your function definition would be

```
function modifyTitle( $item_id ) {
    // ...your code goes here
}
```

If you're going to pass more than 1 parameter you will have to extend your filter addition like so:

```
// 2 arguments are expected
add_filter(  'wpse31787_the_title', array($this, 'modifyTitle'), null, 2 );
```

So, if I put the all the bits together I would have something like this:

```
class New_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function __construct() {
        add_filter(  'wpse31787_the_title', array($this, 'modifyTitle'), null, 2 );
    }

    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
        $output .= apply_filters( 'wpse31787_the_title', $item->title );
    }

    function modifyTitle( $title ){
        return $title . ' << ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! But just one question, why is the apply_filter's hook different from the add_filter?

Comment: Mistake on my part, copied the line from your code and forgot to change the filter name, I edited the post; filter name must be the same throughout. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: It's okay I wasn't even sure if it was a mistake! thanks again!